# duplicate content issues for login page

Tags: magento, seo

I am using SEOmoz to evaluate my store from an SEO perspective.  It is throwing Duplicate Content errors for the customer login page.  A typical URL will look like this:

www.site.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5tbW1zcGVjaW9zYS5jb20vcmV2aWV3L3Byb2R1Y3QvbGlzdC9pZC8xOTYvY2F0ZWdvcnkvNC8jcmV2aWV3LWZvcm0%2C/

I have configured the header links including login to use "rel=nofollow", but perhaps I need to add the "canonical" tag to the login page.  How would I go about doing this in XML?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really just add that to your disallow list in your robots.txt file. That's the easiest method.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /customer/
```

More information on [RogerBot](http://www.seomoz.org/dp/rogerbot).

Comment: Mostly I'm just trying to get confirmation about whether or not this is being penalized by google, since I have "nofollow".  Won't disallowing cause google to through an access denied error of some kind?  which matters more?  Are SEOmoz's error messages really inconsequential for these multiple urls-- are they caused by multiple sessions initiated by their crawler and if so, what is the smart way to tell it that this is OK?

Comment: There is no reason for Google to index a customer page. There are a lot of pages they don't care about, and this does help you SEO-wise. As long as you match the correct directory there is nothing to worry about.